# Context: Surface tension. Is the interface more dense than the bulk?

Tags: forces, surface-tension

Considering, the phenomenon of surface tension, is the interface of the liquid more dense than the bulk phase? Considering, if it were more dense, the phenomenon of surface tension would be explained, more dense, would result in greater strength at the surface. However, i've found various answers that state the interface is of higher density, while answers that state the interface is of lower density. Which one is the definite correct one?

Comment: "At liquid–air interfaces, surface tension results from the greater attraction of liquid molecules to each other (due to cohesion) than to the molecules in the air (due to adhesion)" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_tension